# How do I allow an email discussion list in MOSS to collect messages from any email sender

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-discussion-board

I have a Sharepoint discussion list that belongs to an Exchange list with the idea that it will be able to archive discussions on that list and make them generally accessible, searcheable and so on.

The problem is that although I have checked the "Accept e-mail messages from any sender" option on the discussion board, it still appears to only be seeing emails from members of the domain, nothing sent to the list from outside gets picked up by the Sharepoint site.

Any suggestions as to what else I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality should definitely work regardless of where the messages come from. If they arrive from outside your domain they should appear in the list as being from System Account.

I would check that the messages from outside are being routed correctly through to the SharePoint site. Watch the Exchange logs and `c:\inetpub\mailroot\drop` folder when you send a message from the outside. If the messages are coming through to the drop folder and 'disappearing' then the problem is with SharePoint's processing. Then you need to search your SharePoint logs for the line **`The Incoming E-Mail service has completed a batch`** and see what SP is doing with the messages.

If you don't have further luck you might like to try posting this question with the extra details you find to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) as there are more infrastructure people there.